# Zebra printer print value instead of barcode

Tags: c#, wpf, zebra-printers

i have created a little program 2 years ago using C# and WPF, the client wanted to print labels for every order, and i created it before we get the zebra printer, in that time i installed a barcode font called Free3of9, then when the Zebra printer arrived (a GX420t) i just used the PrintVisual() (the label is on a canvas) function and it just worked.

but now, since the begining of this year the printer does not print the barcode, it instead print the value (the order number). it is very weird becouse if make it to be printed in an hp common printer, it work, and also if i print a word document with a barcode using the free3of9 font the barcode prints well on the label.

i have tried everything, i have reinstalled the free3of9 font, i have reinstalled the controller of the printer, and also i have used the controller of the GC420t printer with the same result (the label was printed out of margins, but it keep printing the value instead of the barcode).

any comment on this topic will be welcomed

Comment: Have you tried to send a ZPL string to the printer? I work a lot with Zebra Printers in my job, and what I have done is to emmulate the label with Zebra Desginer (can be found her https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/zebralink/zebra-designer.html), print it to file to get the zpl code and then send it to the printer

Comment: no, i have not tryed that, i'll do some test, but i will not have the printer in my hands until saturday. thanks for the recommendation